# How to Using the #include in glsl support ARB_shading_language_include

Tags: opengl, glsl

I wan't to use the `#include` macro to include shader files in glsl, and I heard there is a `ARB_shading_language_include` [extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_include.txt) support the `#include` macro. Is there anyone can give me a code snippet showing how to use the `#include` macro?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand about [shading_language_include](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_include.txt) is what it *isn't*. It is not "I `#include` a *file* from the disk." OpenGL doesn't know what files are; it has no concept of the file system.

Instead, you must *pre-load* all of the files you might want to include. So you have a shader string and a filename that you loaded the string from. Essentially, you must build a virtual filesystem within OpenGL.

You use `glNamedStringARB` to upload a string to the virtual filesystem. The name of the string is its full pathname.

Once you've built your virtual filesystem, you must then, for each shader you compile, initialize the extension.

```
#version MY_OPENGL_VERSION //Whatever version you're using.
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_include : require
```

After the `#extension` statement, you may `#include` as you see fit.

Comment: I can't find any documentation about `glNamedStringARB`. What should be the first (`type`) parameter in this case?

Answer (score 14):

I would like to answer 0xbadf00d's question, but lack reputation.

From [ARB/shading_language_include.txt](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_include.txt):
"`<type>` must be `SHADER_INCLUDE_ARB`"

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this in the build for your application and output the already preprocessed by the build files to the files that are installed with and loaded by the app and are passed in to the shader compiler.