# openGL shaders shared variables

Tags: opengl, shader, shared, vertex-shader

My Question is related to multiple shader files using the same data.

I know you can in directX but can you in openGL?

example

vertexShader1 might need to know my cameraViewProjection
vertexShader2 might need to as well

soooo is there a way i can just

"#include" the shared variables file?

like if i wanted to make another file called "ShaderedVariables" an i can put my 
world info there like the cameraView or ViewProjection

i have been looking everywhere but I still don't know if this is possible or not.

Comment: It's not possible to simply "include" another file - the GLSL compiler has no concept of files or inclusion. Still, I found at least one way to accomplish pretty much the same thing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754437/how-to-using-the-include-in-glsl-support-arb-shading-language-include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL does not know how to use the filesystem. It doesn't know that there *is* a filesystem. So it cannot read files.

You could try ARB_shading_language_include (this also doesn't read files; it makes you build a filesystem in-memory). But right now, it seems only NVIDIA supports it, so it's not exactly the most portable solution.

In general, if the definitions are small and few, you just put the same stuff into each shader file:

```
// Shader1:
uniform mat4 cameraMatrix;
void main() {...}

// Shader2:
uniform mat4 cameraMatrix;
void main() {...}
```

If your definitions are more substantial, you can always build your own include system. Note that `glShaderSource` takes *multiple* strings, not just one. So you could simply preface your main shader strings with commonly used definitions, and let each actual shader pick the ones they actually use.

Comment: +1 for building your own system. It's pretty simple and you can set it up however you want. If you want to prepend commonly used uniforms, you can. If you want to have certain keywords at the start of a shader that refer to different sets of uniforms, you can. The system is yours and you can custom-fit functionality to your needs. Also, don't worry too much about only including necessary uniforms, GLSL compilers are usually very good about removing unused uniforms.

Comment: Although you answer states that glShaderSource takes multiple strings, this information can be easily overlooked. I suggest you put stronger emphasis on this. Ideally an own paragraph with a small example.