# How to import libraries in OpenGL GLSL

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

My question is - how to import a library into OpenGL GLSL shader? I mean - is there a way that is supported by OpenGL itself, not a facade over the API which concatenates strings in order to mix shader code with a library code.

Comment: Thx for your question and for the @MikeMx7f answer but it seems to me that there is now appropriate way to make glsl files somekind of moduluar. I also just posted an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604221/how-to-make-glsl-shaders-modular-without-using-string-manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way that is supported by OpenGL itself without extensions. Many engines that wrap OpenGL add their own preprocessor to handle #include macros to solve this problem, but this qualifies as "a facade over the API which concatenates strings in order to mix shader code with a library code."

The [ARB_shading_language_include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754437/how-to-using-the-include-in-glsl-support-arb-shading-language-include) extension provides an OpenGL version of this functionality, but may not be available on your particular machine. For an overview on this extension, see this question: [How to Using the #include in glsl support ARB_shading_language_include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754437/how-to-using-the-include-in-glsl-support-arb-shading-language-include)