# HLSL splitting shader into multiple files

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, hlsl

It might be stupid question, but I was looking for a long time for an answer and I can't find one for my DirectX 11 game engine. For example I have got two pixel shaders **A** and **B** and I don't want to repeat my code for gamma correction. So my idea was to move that to separate hlsl file and include them, but I don't know how to do that. When I was google that I was only able to find informations about .fx workflow, but I'm not using it. When I'm trying to make a new shader I always get an error, that my shaders need to have main function. How can I do this?

EDIT:
As *VTT* suggested I will provide example. Let's say I have my *uber_pixel_shader.hlsl* like this:

```
#include "gamma_utils_shader.hlsl"

...

float4 main(PS_INPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    ...
    finalColor = gammaCorrect(finalColor);

    return float4(finalColor, Alpha);
}
```

And there is no method *gammaCorrect* in HLSL, so I want to include it from another file named *gamma_utils_shader.hlsl*. This file looks like this:

```
float3 gammaCorrect(float3 inputColor)
{
    return pow(inputColor, 1.0f / 2.2f);
}
```

When I'm trying to compile this, the comipler is throwing an error *"Error 3501 'main': entrypoint not found"*. And it's true, becase I don't have main method in this file, but I do not need one. How can I solve this in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Have you looked these links [link1](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1373372/how-to-reuse-hlsl-shader-code.html), [link2](https://www.shawnhargreaves.com/hlsl_fragments/hlsl_fragments.html), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754437/how-to-using-the-include-in-glsl-support-arb-shading-language-include), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243942/opengl-es-2-0-and-higher-how-to-compile-multiple-shader-files-together)

Comment: I saw that, but I wasn't able to do that, because when I add new shader and just try to include it I get an error, due to missing main function.

Comment: [hlsl #include directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-appendix-pre-include), if you are getting an error then you should post mcve

Comment: I have added more informations.

Comment: maybe you are trying to compile `gamma_utils_shader.hlsl` instead of just including it?

Comment: This actually may be the file format bug i had with my msvc using #include within the hlsl file.   Do an experiment.  Copy the function in the file rather than the#include.   If you no longer get the error than you need to save your hlsl file with a slightly different format, i will have to look at my project to tell you the exact format if it is.    I had such an issue in visual studio, and had to select the format under "save as".   If it doesn't fix the entry point issue then can eliminate that as a possibility.

Comment: As per my comment above, this is the issue I had with my #include hlsl files, this may or may not be the issue but for myself it was causing compiling to trip up with the very same error you are getting.    Link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067027/error-x3000-illegal-character-in-shader-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project settings by default specify that an HLSL file should be compiled with the HLSL compiler. This means that during the build, VS queues all your HLSL files, including your include file, for compilation by the compiler with the default entrypoint of `main`. Obviously this is not desired - an include file can't be truly compiled.

To solve the issue, right click on your HLSL include file in the 'Solution Explorer', click 'Properties', and change the 'Item Type' field from "HLSL Compiler" to "Does not participate in build". This will prevent Visual Studio from compiling your include file.

In the future, provide the '.hlsli' extension to your HLSL include files. Visual Studio will open those files with the HLSL editor, but automatically identify them as not participating in the build procedure.

Comment: It is the answer, that I was looking for! Thanks!