# Do GLSL code snippets stored in named strings have to be compileable code to #include via ARB_shading_language_include extension?

Tags: opengl, include, glsl, shader, preprocessor

I learned how to use https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shading_language_include.txt extension thanks to [opengl - How to Using the #include in glsl support ARB_shading_language_include - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754437/how-to-using-the-include-in-glsl-support-arb-shading-language-include). I prepared the following named string and shader:

### option A

```c
// NamedString /lib/VertexData.glsl
struct VertexData {
  vec3 objectPosition;
  vec3 worldPosition;
};

VertexData fillVertexData() {
  VertexData v;
  v.objectPosition = objectPosition;
  v.worldPosition = vec3(worldFromObject * vec4(objectPosition, 1));
  return v
}
```

```c
// MyShader.vert
#version 430
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_include : require

layout(location = 0) in vec3 objectPosition;

uniform mat4 worldFromObject; // Model
uniform mat4 viewFromWorld; // View
uniform mat4 projectionFromView; // Projection

#include "/lib/VertexData.glsl"

out VertexData v;

void main() {
  v = fillVertexData();
  gl_Position = projectionFromView * viewFromWorld * vec4(v.worldPosition, 1);
}
```

When compiling the shader via `glCompileShaderIncludeARB(vertex, 0, NULL, NULL);` I get following error: `Error. Message: 0:18(21): error: 'objectPosition' undeclared.` The `objectPosition` vertex attribute declared in `MyShader.vert` is not recognized.

Whereas if I move the `fillVertexData()` function to `MyShader.vert` shader, it works fine.

### option B

```c
// NamedString /lib/VertexData.glsl
struct VertexData {
  vec3 objectPosition;
  vec3 worldPosition;
};
```

```c
// MyShader.vert
#version 430
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_include : require

layout(location = 0) in vec3 objectPosition;

uniform mat4 worldFromObject; // Model
uniform mat4 viewFromWorld; // View
uniform mat4 projectionFromView; // Projection

#include "/lib/VertexData.glsl"

out VertexData v;

VertexData fillVertexData() {
  VertexData v;
  v.objectPosition = objectPosition;
  v.worldPosition = vec3(worldFromObject * vec4(objectPosition, 1));
  return v
}

void main() {
  v = fillVertexData();
  gl_Position = projectionFromView * viewFromWorld * vec4(v.worldPosition, 1);
}
```

This made me think that the extension checks the scope of variables per named string. But that's not the behavior I expect from an `#include` preprocessor macro system. It should NOT care about variable scopes and just preprocess `MyShader.vert` and compile that one.

I tried option A via `GL_GOOGLE_include_directive` and `glslangValidator -l MyShader.vert` does NOT throw any errors for both options, and generated GLSL code via `-E` looks correct. Which was my expectation.

I read the extension specifications and it didn't mention that variables that are used in a named string should be declared by the time the extension is processing that named string. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this by design of ARB_shading_language_extension? Any suggestions on how I can keep `fillVertexData()` in the named string?

By the way, before writing my own `#include` implementation for my own app, I wanted to exhaust existing solutions. I first tried `glslang` library. But the preprocessor output I get from it is not compileable GLSL: my version of OpenGL does not support `GL_GOOGLE_include_directive` and it fills the code with `#line` directives where the second parameter is NOT an integer but a string (filename) which is not valid GLSL.

Using `ARB_shading_language_extension` was my second attempt of having reusable GLSL code via `#include`s.

Comment: Note that while what you want is intended to be possible, it is generally considered *bad* coding style. Includes are usually not expected to so significantly depend on what was included before them. That is, while includes don't have to be stand-alone, they generally *should be* where possible.

Comment: I see. What you say makes sense. I was going to go back to `glslang` or `libshaderc` and try `GL_GOOGLE_include_directive` with SPIRV compilation in OpenGL, but instead I'll do your advice.

If I declare fillVertexData as `VertexData fillVertexData(mat4 worldFromObject, vec3 objectPosition)` the inclusions work fine, since those variables are now declared as function parameters.

It'll make the call-sites little bit more verbose (since I'm giving so many vertex attribute there) but the snippets are now more portable. Thank you!